# In Ruby, how does one get their IP octet without going through DNS?

Tags: ruby, sockets, ip-address

I can, on some of my systems, get my IP address (192.68.m.n format) by doing this:

```
addr = IPSocket::getAddress(Socket.gethostname())
```

...the trouble is that this only works if the name the local machine uses for itself is the name the DNS server associates with it.

How *&#( hard can it be for ruby to just return its primary interface's IP address?  I have to do this in a platform-independant way or I'd just call ifconfig or ipconfig and parse it.

Comment: Define "primary interface" please. What is the primary interface if the machine has many of them.

Comment: An octet is just 8 bits. You clearly want more than that; better to say "address".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails).  Also `see Socket.getaddrinfo()`

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
require 'socket'
ipaddr = UDPSocket.open {|s| s.connect('65.59.196.211'); s.addr.last }
```

the IP address can be anything that is real (this is the I got for stackoverflow.com), but it should be an IP address reachable on the interface you want to get the IP address for. Since its a UDP socket, no connection is actually attempted, but it does try and figure out what interface to use.