# how to get the ip of visitors with ruby?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using ruby with Sinatra. 
I want get the public ip of visitors and save it in a database, but a don't know how get the ip... Sorry, but I have not found a way to do that.
Guys can help me? Thank you!

Comment: This didn't work..??. `ip_addr = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: This might also help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465476/rails-get-client-ip-address

Comment: And this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226959/how-to-get-client-ip-and-server-ip-using-rails .. Please try to google something before just giving up on it.. and show some efforts and show us then and only then we can help... Thank you..

Comment: Except all those examples are for rails, so please try reading the question before posting snide comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Sinatra documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object), you can use

```
request.ip
```