# How to find the local port a rails instance is running on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I would like my Rails app instances to register themselves on a "I'm up" kind of thing I'm playing with, and I'd like it to be able to mention what local port it's running on. I can't seem to find how to do it - in fact just finding out its IP is tricky and needs a bit of a hack.

But no problem, I have the IP - but how can I find what port my mongrel/thin/webrick server is running on?

To be super explicit, if I start a rails app using script/server -p 3001, what can I do to pull that 3001 inside the app.

Comment: Whereabouts are you putting the code which does the registering?

Comment: I would like it to be in an initializer but it could be anyway really. The important thing is it's able to announce itself to another machine - "hi, i was started on port #{PORT}" - where port could be anything.

Basically, Rails equivalent to Sinatra::Application.port.

Comment: Most answers to the hostname question also answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 21):

You can call `Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]` to get the port that your Rails server is running on. This will parse the `-p 3001` args from your `rails server` command, or default to port `3000`.

Comment: This will work in the initialiser as it doesn't depend on the request object.

Comment: `(rdb:1) Rails::Server
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Rails::Server`

Comment: Try `Rack::Server.new.options[:Port]` in newer versions of Rails

Comment: `Rack::Server.new.options[:Port]` always returns 9292

Comment: I found `Rack::Server.new.options[:Port]` return the port if specified with '-p' option (Rails 5.1.1).

Answer (score 15):

From inside any controller action, check the content of *request.port*, thus:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    raise "I'm running on port #{request.port}."
  end
end
```

Comment: So simple and so easily overlooked.  I thought about this for a few minutes and was thinking out round about ways of getting it. This question is a good reminder for me to review request again.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/AbstractRequest.html

Comment: Precise for localhost, but does not work when behind an Apache Server or in a cluster setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea how to access that programmatically, ie something I can do inside script/console? After all, if I need to access it via HTTP, that means I already know the port!

Answer (score 11):

**Two ways.**

If you're responding to a request in a controller or view, use the request object:

```
request.port
```

If you're in an initialiser and don't have access to the request object use the server options hash:

```
Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]
```

Comment: `(rdb:1) Rails::Server
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Rails::Server`

Comment: @zuba, that's interesting. Did that occur in your initializer?

Comment: Sorry, no, that occured in my controller rspec test debug console

Comment: You may have to require the appropriate library first.

    `require 'rails/commands/server'`

Comment: @SethJeffery, it worked, but i have a little warning: By requiring rails server commands, you can't pass arguments to cucumber/rspec because the rails server launcher will raise an exception claiming that he got wrong arguments.

Answer (score 9):

I played around with this a bit, and this might be the best solution for Rails 5.1:

```
Rails::Server::Options.new.parse!(ARGV)[:Port]
```

Comment: it returns `nil` when no explicit port specified

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 5.1 development server.

```
if Rack::Server.new.options[:Port] != 9292 # rals s -p PORT
  local_port = Rack::Server.new.options[:Port]
else
  local_port = (ENV['PORT'] || '3000').to_i # ENV['PORT'] for foreman
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Building on the other answers (which saved my bacon!), I expanded this to give sane fallbacks:

In development:

```
port = Rails::Server::Options.new.parse!(ARGV)[:Port] || 3000 rescue 3000
```

In all other env's:

```
port = Rails::Server::Options.new.parse!(ARGV)[:Port] || 80 rescue 80
```

The `rescue 80` covers you if you're running `rails console`. Otherwise, it raises `NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Server`. (Maybe also early in initializers? I forget...)

The `|| 80` covers you if no -p option is given to server. Otherwise you get nil.

Answer (score 0):

For Puma servers, you have to use this:

```rb
Puma::Server.current.connected_port
=> 3001
```