# How do I get the host and port in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails Model, I want to be able to find out the host and port.  For example, if I am in a test environment it would return `http://localhost:3000/`  and if I was in production it would return something like `http://my.application.com/`?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the local port a rails instance is running on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554267/how-to-find-the-local-port-a-rails-instance-is-running-on) for the port, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails for the host.

Answer (score 31):

```
"#{root_url}"
```

which should be declared in your routes.rb

Comment: this is what I was looking for.  request.host_with_port was working for me at first, but I needed the leading `HTTP://`.  this works just like any other url / path helper.

Comment: I think is answer is much better then the rest.. No request inspection, just plain router helper method

Comment: Good, but hacky and dangerous. Assumes root path is "/", and could introduce bugs if someone changes root path to ie "/Home" and does not update relevant code...

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo How so? The root path or url is set in `routes.rb` so if you were to change the root path, it would be changed in `routes.rb` and `root_url` would reflect that. If you're not updating the `routes.rb` file when making a change to your root path, you've got bigger problems to deal with.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but my point is that is not good to assume that host+port is and will always be the same as root_url. If you want host and port, you don't want something that looks like host and port right now, you actually fetch the host and port. yiwen answer is the correct one

Comment: thanks, dude!! it was a nightmare to get the hostname! I'm amazed that such simple thing is not easily possible in rails URL helpers!

Answer (score 25):

`host_with_port` should work for you:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Http/URL/host_with_port

Answer (score 21):

You can use this

```
<%= request.protocol + request.host_with_port %>
#=> https://example.com:3000
<%= request.protocol + request.host %>
#=> https://example.com
```

When you use in string concatenation

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/book/1"
# https://example.com:3000/book/1
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get those values in your controllers (request.host, request.port etc.).

You'd have to give that to your models via parameters as the request object is only available in the controllers.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers provided work in controllers or views but can't provide host name in eg: messaging jobs.  Action mailer has it's own configuration for this that you're likely using anyway.

```rb
# Access host from anywhere 
Rails.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]

# Defined in development.rb/test.rb/production.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.example.com' }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get full uri (http://localhost:3000/ or http://my.application.com/ etc) with `request_uri`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/AbstractRequest/request_uri

Comment: Since Rails 3 `request_uri` is deprecated. Use `fullpath` instead.

Comment: I still found it via Google, so others will as well. :)

Comment: If someone still searches for the answer: `request.base_url` in controller.

Answer (score -2):

Request.host

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Request.html#M000712

Comment: it doesn't give the port