# Base URL of Rails app in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, request

In order to be able to see if a User has shared my page on Facebook, I want to be able to create this kind of URLs:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stylehatch.co/some_unique_user_token
```

Where http://stylehatch.co would need to be my base URL.  I am thinking on having a method in the User model that will build and return that URL, but I can't access root_url from within my model.

How can I get the base URL of my application from a Model?

Say if my urls look like this:

```
http://myapp.com/users/new

http://myapp.com/users/2/show
```

How can I get the "http://myapp.com" from my model?  I have added:

```
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

in my model, but it seems that root_url is nil.  Any thoughts? Is this correct to be a Model method, or should I place it in a helper?

Thanks

Comment: Just for some context, what are you wanting to do with the base URL within a model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the host and port in a Rails applicaiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813290/how-do-i-get-the-host-and-port-in-a-rails-applicaiton)

Comment: Let me edit and add some context.

Comment: By way of clarification, the answer that was accepted doesn't actually answer the question as it is described in the title. That answer tells how to get it in the controller. What if you need it in the model and you're not coming to the model via the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use environment variables:

## in environment

```
ROOT_URL=http://myapp.com
```

## in-app

```
ENV['ROOT_URL']
```

Comment: Speransky, do you think is correct to have that in the model though, and pass the url as a parameter? Or do you think this belongs to be in a helper?

Comment: In the situation that the OP described, and in situations like sending out emails that link back to your site, you do generally need some part of your app (whether or not it's the model) to be aware of your application's base url. [@earth2jason's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24371267/1998680) below seems a good approach for that.

Comment: This is not a valid answer to the OP.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to get the root URL in your model, what I did is call an ENV variable.

If you haven't already, go ahead and create .env in the root directory of your applicatoin and set in development to:

```
ROOT_URL=http://localhost
```

In your production environment set:

```
ROOT_URL=https://mydomain.com
```

Of course this is hard coded so the pitfall is that you need to remember to change this when changing domains and each environment's file must be different.

And be sure this is also in your gitignore since other sensitive data will be stored here.

In your model you call by:
    ENV['ROOT_URL']