# put root_url as hyperlinks in axlsx gem

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, axlsx

I am generating a sheet using axlsx gem where I have to concat the image url with the root url.
Right now I am doing this in the following way-

> sheet.add_hyperlink location: 'http://localhost:3000'+user.file.url,
>   ref: sheet_row.cells[7] if user.file.present?

What is the convenient way to specify the URL? I do not want to put http://localhost:3000.

Comment: "#{Rails.root}"+user.file.url

Comment: This gives the file location

Comment: try with request.host

Comment: I have tried this. Still no luck

Comment: what is the error or output you are getting if you use "request.host" ?

Comment: it shows-
file:///home/Downloads/localhost/uploads/user/file/user_id/file_name

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813290/how-do-i-get-the-host-and-port-in-a-rails-application