# How to know the port number of the running rails server in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I need to run an external script inside an RSpec test and to do so I need to know port number of the rails server running for the RSpec test.

Comment: You mean, feature specs? Which launch an external browser?

Comment: No, it's a custom ruby script.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, that's not what I was asking. What kind of specs are you talking about? Most of them do not start a rails server at all.

Comment: In a controller spec, which specs start a server?

Comment: Controller specs do not start a server. Feature specs (with capybara) do.

Comment: Okay, using capybara how can I get the port number?

Comment: Get it from the request environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813290/how-do-i-get-the-host-and-port-in-a-rails-application and pass as script's argument