# How to tell which port Rails is running on in an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Is there a way to tell which port a Rails application (or a generic Rack app) is running on
in an initializer ?

I would like to be able to load a different configuration based on the port or the host name, in order to connect to a host-specific FaceBook application.

I'm using Rails 2.3.5.

Comment: If you don't find any solutions you should try this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554267/how-to-find-the-local-port-a-rails-instance-is-running-on/1554523#1554523.

Comment: Yup, getting the port from the request is pretty straightforward, but in the initializer I don't have any requests. I'm looking for something similar to what's mentioned in linked question: Sinatra::Application.port, but for Rails, not Sinatra.

Comment: More general question that does not require initializer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554267/how-to-find-the-local-port-a-rails-instance-is-running-on (and as such has answers for both controllers and initializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the lack of answers here and this thread on rubyforum: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/196017#new , I think that
there probably isn't a standard way to tell the port.

Answer (score 2):

This is not very clean but this is a way you can get the port you declared when calling :
    `rails server -p portnumber`
wherever you want in your application (for rails 3).

Here is my scripts/rails.rb file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" 
# with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.
ENV['PORT']=ARGV[3]
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

Then whenever you want to get the port number of your server, all you need to do is call `ENV['PORT']`.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]` to get the port that your Rails server is running on. This will parse the `-p` arg from your `rails server` command, or default to port `3000`.

Comment: I'm getting uninitialized constant `Rails::Server` when I try to do this in my Rails 3.2 app.