# Getting the server port outside a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to register a callback URL to my Rails server from a third-party application, and to perform this registering on startup so I can start catching notifications.

Looking [at this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554267/how-to-find-the-local-port-a-rails-instance-is-running-on) I see advice like:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    raise "I'm running on port #{request.port}."
  end
end
```

This is no good as I am not in a Controller. Next there is:

```
Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]
```

However, I get this error from my code and `rails console`:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'Server' for Rails::Module
```

I've got the host name successfully using `Socket.gethostname`, but how do I get the port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cant   access `request.port` is that the request object is tied to a clients request which does only exist when you look at a specific request. What you want is accessing the webservers configuration. Thats a completely other thing.

You might solve this looking up the pid of the webserver which is possible by accessing the applicationwide `$$` variable which contains the pid of the process executing the ruby code. Then you can lookup the port used by this process. You can du this using the `system` command which executes external applications. Here is a post that explains how ou can identify a port that belongs to a process:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

This will work when there is only one process that is running the whole application. When using a combination of thin and nginx this wont work because the process running the code isn't the process thats running the webserver.