# Running Rails on Unicorn via Pow, is it possible to know what port Unicorn is running on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, unicorn, foreman, rack-pow

In my Ruby on Rails dev environment, I am starting Rails and Unicorn via Foreman in the typical way:

(Procfile:)

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

I am also running Pow.  But not as a webserver. I'm just using Pow to direct http requests from mydomain.dev (port 80) to the port Unicorn is listening on.

You can do this by creating a pow file (`mydomain.dev`) containing the port number Unicorn is running on.

**Given this setup, is it possible in my rails code to know what the port I started Unicorn on?**

I'm only wanting to know this in my dev environment, it's not a production issue.

In my Rails code, I've tried a few different things, but none of them work:

- `Unicorn::Configurator::RACKUP[:port]` - returned nothing
- `Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]` - doesn't exist in Rails 4
- `Rack::Server.new.options[:Port]` - returns default rack port (9292) not the one configured for *this rack instance*.

  Is there a way to get the current rack instance from rails?
- `request.port` - returns 80, which is the port that Pow is listening on. Pow is routing http traffic to Unicorn, which is on a different port.

None of these give me the port that Unicorn is running on.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** If you're wondering why I want to know this, it's because in my dev environment, I'm trying to dynamically create configuration files for Pow, so I can route http requests to Unicorn on the correct port.

Answer (score 0):

If you're responding to a request in a controller or view, use the request object - this should work, although you say it does not:

```
request.port
```

If you're in an initialiser :

```
Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]
```

[How to find the local port a rails instance is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554267/how-to-find-the-local-port-a-rails-instance-is-running-on)

Comment: request.port returns 80. I think that's because I'm using Pow, and Pow is listening on 80, and then forwards the traffic to Unicorn on a different port.

Comment: `Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]` is the same as `Rack::Server.new.options[:Port]`, which is what is used in newer versions of Rails.   I didn't know that only worked from an initializer, so I'll try that out now.

Comment: I don't think it matters where you call `Rack::Server.new.options[:Port]`, it works outside of initializers too.

But that will return the default port for a rack server, which is 9292.  It doesn't return the actual rack server instance with the configured port.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to access it via `ENV['PORT']`, given it's value has been set to the `$PORT` environment variable.

Comment: No, that won't work. Because $PORT is being set by Foreman in the `.foreman` file.  I *was* using that - however it doesn't allow me to have different $PORT values for development and testing environments.

Comment: The question was: "to know what the port I started Unicorn on" and you said "`$PORT` is being set by Foreman'. Given `foreman` is starting `Unicorn`, why isn't this exactly what you need? You can have different ports by supplying different values to `foreman` on the command line: `$ foreman start --port 2000`. I've never used `foreman` for running my tests, the standard ruby tooling + `bundler` typically give me everything I need without the extract overhead of a process manager.

Comment: OK, I didn't know I could pass the port to Foreman on the command line.  I think I would want to avoid that if possible though.

Comment: I think my idea of running the test server via foreman is not a good anyway.   I'm mainly trying to run feature tests via selenium.  I don't like how the test server that Capybara starts works, and wanted it to use the same unicorn setup that the dev environment uses, but just on a different port. The issue was is my app dynamically creates virtual directory files for Pow, and it needs to know the correct port.

Anyway... I sort of have something working now. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bad idea, but whatever:

```
uport = `netstat -n --listening --tcp -p | grep unicorn | sed 's/.*:\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/'`
```

Answer (score 0):

I've sort of found a way to do this.

1. Create separate config files for Unicorn. `unicorn.development.rb` and `unicorn.test.rb`
2. Install the `dotenv-rails` gem
3. Inside my unicorn config files, do something like this:
       # unicorn.development.rb:

   ```
   require "dotenv"
   Dotenv.load(
     "./.env.local",
     "./.env.development",
     "./.env"
   )

   if ENV['UNICORN_PORT'].nil?
     throw 'UNICORN_PORT not set in environment!'
   end

   worker_processes 3
   timeout 30
   preload_app true

   listen ENV['UNICORN_PORT'], backlog: 64

   ... rest of unicorn config...




   # unicorn.testing.rb:

   require "dotenv"
   Dotenv.load(
     "./.env.local",
     "./.env.testing",
     "./.env"
   )

   if ENV['UNICORN_PORT'].nil?
     throw 'UNICORN_PORT not set in environment!'
   end

   worker_processes 3
   timeout 30
   preload_app true

   listen ENV['UNICORN_PORT'], backlog: 64

   ... rest of unicorn config...
   ```
4. In my `.env.development` and `.env.testing` environment files, set the UNICORN_PORT environment variable
5. Make sure you use the correct Unicorn config file to start the app. This can be done by using separate Procfiles for dev and testing.

   ```
   # Procfile.dev
   web: bundle exec unicorn -c ./config/unicorn.development.rb

   # Procfile.testing
   web: bundle exec unicorn -c ./config/unicorn.testing.rb
   ```

This appears to mostly work, but is not without it's issues...