# Rails 6.1.3 - Get ARGV parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, argv

I am upgrading from Rails 4.1.5 to rails 6.1.3. I want to get the arguments when starting the rails server (port, binding, ...)

In my current APP I have an initializer that gets the `ARGV` array.
In Rails 6 I tried exactly the same but did not get any ARGV elements (the ARGV is empty `[]`).

I have followed this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554267/how-to-find-the-local-port-a-rails-instance-is-running-on) but without success.

What can I do to get the parameters?
I am running the rails 6 APP using docker.

Thanks in advance!

#### UPDATE

I encountered this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40945) that fixed a bug in ARGV. Also I tried using ARGV in Rails 6.0.3.5 and it works. After this version it does not work.

Comment: Not a direct solution but rather a workaround: Gather the information you seek not from ARGV but from ENV and/or Rails config (which is setup based on ARGV and default values).

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's what I will gona do. But the migration would have been smoother if the ARGV option was still available (and I am migrating a lot of apps).