# javascript getting client ip

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I found how to get client ip by answer here:
[Can I perform a DNS lookup (hostname to IP address) using client-side Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript)

But I don't understand how to use it.

This is what I have:

```
var user;
if ($('#user-id').length) {
    user = $('#user-id').text();
} else {
    http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip
    function getip(json){
       user = json.ip;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to include the url and how to use the getip function.

I need to set the user to the ip address in the else.

Thanks!

Comment: As Mohamed pointed out, this requires help from the server. If you tell us what backend framework/language are you using, you'd get more concrete answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could make a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) call:

```
$.getJSON('http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=?',
        function(data){
          alert(data.ip);
        });
```

Probably easier to understand - an alternative, without jQuery, would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getip(data){
      alert(data.ip);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip">
</script>
```

Note that when you include http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip as a script in your HTML you get valid JavaScript as response:

```
getip({"ip": "147.234.2.5", "address":"147.234.2.5"});
```

This line executes your function with the proper parameter. Note that the function's name is given to it by query string.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You can only access your domain from JavaScript, you cannot do cross-domain communication with JavaScript unless you do the communication with [iframes](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).</del>

If you have a dynamic backend such as PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, CGI, etc you can easily fetch the IP address from the user visiting your page. Each language has their own mechanism.

- PHP: [$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
- Python: [socket.getaddrinfo](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo)
- Java: [NetworkInterface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) class
- Ruby: [Socket.gethostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: You can definitely fire crossdomain requests. Read on about the `Access-Control` response headers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the link, here it is: [`Access-Control`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a random, free-floating URL in your javascript syntax.

This is how to make remote JSON request with jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

I would suggest you get more familiar with javascript in general.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userip;
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("Your IP is :", userip);
</script>
```

Here is the url of this library: http://l2.io/