# Ruby: get local IP (nix)

Tags: ruby, unix, ip

I need to get my IP (that is DHCP). I use this in my `environment.rb`:

```
LOCAL_IP = `ifconfig wlan0`.match(/inet addr:(\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)/)[1] || "localhost"
```

But is there rubyway or more clean solution?

Comment: There might be multiple local IP addresses. Commonly, the address to use (e.g. for opening a listening socket) is specified through a configuration file.

Comment: I need wlan0 inet address. I get it through DHCP from my wifi router. So for my development envirement I need to set new IP each time I reconnect to my router. So now I want to get it auto from system. I use unix command to get it and it works fine, but now I am looking for more rubyway solution.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: yep. it's duplicate. but I can't delete it

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A server typically has more than one interface, at least one private and one public.

Since all the answers here deal with this simple scenario, a cleaner way is to ask Socket for the current `ip_address_list()` as in:

```
require 'socket'

def my_first_private_ipv4
  Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4_private?}
end

def my_first_public_ipv4
  Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4? and !intf.ipv4_loopback? and !intf.ipv4_multicast? and !intf.ipv4_private?}
end
```

Both returns an `Addrinfo` object, so if you need a string you can use the `ip_address()` method, as in:

```
ip= my_first_public_ipv4.ip_address unless my_first_public_ipv4.nil?
```

You can easily work out the more suitable solution to your case changing Addrinfo methods used to filter the required interface address.

Comment: BTW, I think this is not available in v1.8

Comment: Fo completeness, to get the IP address: Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4_private?}.getnameinfo[0]

Comment: As a note, ip_address_list was introduced in 1.9.x it seems

Answer (score 11):

```
require 'socket'

def local_ip
  orig = Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup  
  Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup =true # turn off reverse DNS resolution temporarily
  UDPSocket.open do |s|
    s.connect '64.233.187.99', 1 #google
    s.addr.last
  end
ensure
  Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = orig
end

puts local_ip
```

Found [here](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/get-your-local-ip-address/).

Comment: This method will crash if the machine live in LAN which not connect to  WAN. I meet crash problem in the case.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a small modification of steenslag's solution

```
require "socket"
local_ip = UDPSocket.open {|s| s.connect("64.233.187.99", 1); s.addr.last}
```

Comment: Why is that an improvement?  @steenslag will run faster as it disables DNS lookups, shorter code is not always better