# Get own IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to get my own IP address with Rails?

When I do it like this I got: `127.0.0.1`

```
@ip = request.remote_ip
```

Is there any way to get the Public IP?

Comment: Where is your server running and where is your browser running that you make the request from? Which machine(s)?

Comment: my rails server running via localhost,. but i need to get the system IP?   or the public IP? the 192.168.2.9 is my private address have any way to get that?

Comment: Here is another question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029427/ruby-get-local-ip-nix

Comment: How to get the public IP address?

Comment: i have used the same to get the private ip request.remote_ip

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try:

```
require 'socket'
ip=Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4_private?}
ip.ip_address if ip
```

Comment: an even more concise way to write it would be:

`Socket.ip_address_list.detect(&:ipv4_private?).try(:ip_address)`

Comment: As a note, Socket.ip_address_list was introduced in 1.9.x

Answer (score 1):

I believe `request.env['SERVER_NAME']` works, if you want to reflect the server base address back

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer this question. I think someone else can find this answer helpful.

**Problem:**

I am developing a mobile app. So, When I `debug`/`hot reload`/`live reload` the app in real mobile device. Images url does not work with `localhost:3000`.

Images works with ip like this: `http://192.168.0.102:3000/user/1/profile-223hfkj33.jpg`

`Problem is` Every time I turn on laptop and connect to wifi router, laptop ip changes. So, every-time I need to change `asset_host` in `environments/development.rb` file.

Looking at previous answers I found a solution:

**Solution:**

in `environments/development.rb` I write this code:

```rb
server_address = "#{Socket.ip_address_list.detect(&:ipv4_private?).try(:ip_address)}:3000"
config.asset_host = server_address

puts "Server address: #{server_address}"
# when I run `rails s`, this line prints server address in console
```

So, It sets `asset_host` like this: `192.168.0.102:3000` 
And when I turn on laptop, laptop gets new ip address and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the page using your IP, not localhost. I.e, `192.168.2.9:3000` in case of the default development environment would yield:

```
request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
#=> 192.168.2.9
```

or:

```
request.remote_ip 
#=> 192.168.2.9
```

Comment: unfortunately I believe these pertain to the client "making the request" not the server's IP address...

Answer (score 0):

As your request is local to the server, it returns the "localhost" address, i.e. `127.0.0.1`.
If you request it from a machine hosted on the internet, it will give you a static IP of the remote server.

If you want the static IP of own internet then visit http://ping.eu and you can see your public IP.