# How to use ifconfig to check my ipAddress?

Tags: ifconfig

I'm new to mac.

I'm mobile application engineer and developing a mobile app with rails API.

My mobile app can't fetch data from the Rails API.

I was told to use ifconfig, and put en0's IP to rails's address.

I did 
    ifconfig en0
it shows

```
ether 5x:5x:ca:f6:0x:ax
```

What is rails's address?
I was told to rewrite rails's address by using ifconfig.

My question is How to use iconfig with Rails API?

Answer (score 0):

`ifconfig` should have an output of multiple lines for multiple interfaces. Your local ip should be referred just below the ether mention. ( ether is your **mac address** not your IP).

Too find your IP search for something like this ( *for home or generally small networks* )

```
inet 192.168.x.x
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to know is How to use iconfig withRails.

Comment: ah, sorry did not get the question right. So what do you need? Get your local IP through ruby?

Comment: I can't fetch deta from rails API with react-native app.
I was told to change settings of Rails by using iconfig.

Comment: You can get the address of `en0` (machines IP) using the commands referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029427/ruby-get-local-ip-nix), without using ifconfig. But I still don't know if I get the question right

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll try your solution.
My question is How to set my mobile application's address in my rails dev API?
I' m new to rails so, I don't know how to set my mobile app's address to Rails API.