# How to get Host name in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 2.3, I could just use HOST to get my hostname but it seems it's not available anymore. What can I use instead?

I just want something that returns `localhost:xxxx` (with real port number) when I run the code from my machine, and `http://www.mysite.com` when I run it in production.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the Hostname or IP in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have several options:

- call system's hostname command (assuming it's *nix): `` `hostname ```
- use the socket gem:

  `require 'socket'`

  `Socket.gethostname`
- in case you just want to know the current domain the request visits: `request.domain`

**Update**

From the request object, we can fetch both the host and the port, please check out these methods:

- `request.protocol`
- `request.host`
- `request.port`

You could build the full url from these methods.

From my personal experience, for most projects you might have a fixed domain for each environment, and usually configure that in a yaml file or so (for example, to send email and use urls with domain name in the email body, we usually read the config and set options for url helper). So I usually just read the current environment's urls configuration and use them from the code.

Comment: James, thanks for your answer, but I think I didn't phrase my question properly. I made a quick edit. I tried your easy solution on my local machine and it returns my machine's name while I'd like to get 'localhost:3000'...

Comment: Can i call this methods from a Model? It gives me an error undefined method request

Comment: @Inquisitive Only controller has access to `request`. It's a bad idea to let model have knowledge of request.

Answer (score 25):

Use the following method on ActionController:

```
request.host_with_port
```

Answer (score 19):

It’s actually easy. The best suggestion I have for solving this problem is that you create a before_filter that sets it on each request in ApplicationController.rb like so:

```
 before_filter :set_mailer_host

  def set_mailer_host
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
  end
```