# Rails reverse autolink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my Rails app:

```
link_to('???',{:controller => 'profile', :action => 'show', :id => id})
```

I want to get rid of '???' and it to show the dynamically generated URL. How do I this? It's kind of like what the [autolink gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) does, but I want Rails to convert URL options into text, not vice versa.

Comment: If link will convert into text then how it will be clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link_to(nil,{:controller => 'profile', :action => 'show', :id => id})
```

From the [link_to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

> If nil is passed as the name the value of the link itself will become the name

Answer (score 1):

Use `url_for()` to get the string.

```
url_for({:controller => 'profile', :action => 'show', :id => id)}
```

In the code:

```
url_hash = {:controller => 'profile', :action => 'show', :id => id}
link_to(url_for(url_hash), url_hash)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154914/how-to-get-host-name-in-rails-3) to also get the host name:

```
url_hash = {:controller => 'profile', :action => 'show', :id => id}
link_to("#{request.host_with_port}#{url_for(url_hash)}", url_hash)
```