# Get root_url in a Rails service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The app I'm working on makes heavy use of [Rails services](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services). My problem is I need to get the root url of the app, similar to how you would use `root_url` in a view, but this doesn't work in a service. Does anyone know a way to do this other than entering the url in each of my environment setting files?

**Edit**

I tried using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url` as it suggests to do here stackoverflow.com/a/5456103/772309 but it expects you to pass the `:host => ...` in as a parameter. That's what Im trying to find.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Rails Routing Helpers (i.e. mymodel\_path(model)) be Used in Models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models)

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I tried using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url` as it suggests to do here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5456103/772309 but it expects you to pass the `:host => ...` in as a parameter. That's what Im trying to find.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154914/how-to-get-host-name-in-rails-3 might help there.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I tried that but I'm having the same problem as the first commenter - "I tried your easy solution on my local machine and it returns my machine's name while I'd like to get 'localhost:3000'"

Comment: How about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17574412/634576

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I got a `undefined local variable or method request` error since a Rails service doesn't receive an http request like a controller normally would.

Comment: Presumably your service is used in a controller action. The idea is to save the host:port in `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]` in the controller, then retrieve it from there in your service.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth This should work but I think I'm going to just set it in my environment settings. There's a good chance I'm going to need it somewhere else down the road. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I've read from the linked 'Rails services' article, the services are just plain old ruby objects. If that's the case, then you'd need to pass the `root_url` from the controller to the initializer of your service object. To extend the example from that article:

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  private
  ...

  def register_with_credit_card_service
    CreditCardService.new({
      card: params[:stripe_token],
      email: params[:user][:email],
      root_url: root_url
    }).create_customer
  end
end
```

CreditCardService

```
class CreditCardService
  def initialize(params)
    ...
    @root_url = params[:root_url]
  end
end
```

EDIT: Alternative solution that leverages the Rails.application.config

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_root_url

  def set_root_url
    Rails.application.config.root_url = root_url
  end
end

class CreditCardService
  def some_method
    callback_url = "#{Rails.application.config.root_url}/my_callback"
  end
end
```

Comment: That's definitely one way to do it, and yes services are just plain ruby objects. The problem with my current use case is that I would have to pass it through multiple services and to a separate server and back, obviously not the most elegant solution. Your answer would work best for most cases however.

Comment: Understood, then take a look at the edit that I included. I used the UserController again because that was the original example from the article. I typically start with an ApplicationController and have all of my other controllers extend it. I would add the before_filter there that will set the config.root_url for all routes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're opposed to putting it in your environment folders you could do something like below in your App controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    if Rails.env.production?
      {:host => "myproduction.com"}
    else  
      {}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not opposed to putting it in my environments folder, was just hoping there was a native Rails method I could call to get the hostname. Its looking like my environment settings is the way to go.