# How to get IP address of the host server in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a server written in Ruby. One of the purposes is to send a confirmation email when a user registers with a link. That link needs to have the ip address of the server in it. How can I get the ip address of the server locally so that I can put that as part of the email message that I send to the client.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

try `request.fullpath` from your controller

Answer (score -1):

I think ActionDispatch::Request#remote_ip (request.remote_ip in your controller`s action) is what you are looking for.