# Use root_url in config.action_mailer.default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, actionmailer

I have a staging app and a production app on Heroku.  I'm using Devise for authentication, which for my production app requires that I set

```
# in config/environments/production.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myapp.com' }
```

For my staging app, I have to set host: 'myapp-staging.herokuapp.com'

I would rather not have to change it when deploying to different apps, as I am bound to forget that at some point.  Is there a way to use root_url in place of the string for host?

Comment: The chosen solution [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/getting-the-hostname-or-ip-in-ruby-on-rails) worked great for me.